# SOLVED - Program does not count numbers of a field rigth

Tags: python, minesweeper

I tried to program Minesweeper in python. Counting the numbers of an field surrounded by bombs, I get an worse problem - no error...

My code is:

```
for i in range(len(bombs)):
    numbers[bombs[i]] = -1

    if (bombs[i][0] > 0):
        if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] != -1):
            numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] + 1
            if (bombs[i][1] > 0):
                if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] != -1):
                    numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] + 1
            if (bombs[i][1] < heigth-step-1):
                if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+step)] != -1):
                    numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+step)] + 1

    if (bombs[i][0] < width-step-1):
        if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]+0)] != -1):
            numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]+0)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]+0)] + 1
            if (bombs[i][1] > 0):
                if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]-step)] != -1):
                    numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]-step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]-step)] + 1
            if (bombs[i][1] < heigth-step-1):
                if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]+step)] != -1):
                    numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]+step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]+step, bombs[i][1]+step)] + 1

    if (bombs[i][1] > 0):
        if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]+0, bombs[i][1]-step)] != -1):
            numbers[(bombs[i][0]+0, bombs[i][1]-step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]+0, bombs[i][1]-step)] + 1

    if (bombs[i][1] < heigth-step-1):
        if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]+0, bombs[i][1]+step)] != -1):
            numbers[(bombs[i][0]+0, bombs[i][1]+step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]+0, bombs[i][1]+step)] + 1
```

> step  = size of the fields

> bombs = all bombs in an array

Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOxi4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a problem is in this section of code:

```py
            if (bombs[i][0] > 0):
                # This bomb is not in the leftmost column of the grid
        #        print(numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)])
                if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] != -1):
                    # The cell to the left is not a bomb, so add one to its count
                    numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] + 1

                    if (bombs[i][1] > 0):
                        # This bomb is not in the top row of the grid.
                        if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] != -1):
                            # The cell above and to the left is not a bomb, so add one to its count
                            numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] + 1
```

Note that we only look at the cell above and to the left of the bomb and add one to it if it isn't a bomb *if the cell to the left is also not a bomb*.  This is incorrect: for any bomb, we need to check the cell above and to the left of it whether or not the cell to the left of it is also a bomb.

What you want to do is to remove a level of indentation from the third `if` statement in the above:

```py
            if (bombs[i][0] > 0):
                # This bomb is not in the leftmost column of the grid
        #        print(numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)])
                if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] != -1):
                    # The cell to the left is not a bomb, so add one to its count
                    numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]+0)] + 1

                # This line will now be reached if there is another bomb to the left of bombs[i].
                if (bombs[i][1] > 0):
                    # This bomb is not in the top row of the grid.
                    if (numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] != -1):
                        # The cell above and to the left is not a bomb, so add one to its count
                        numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] + 1
```

You would also make the same changes to the other three `if` statements that handle adding one to the counts for diagonally-adjacent squares in other directions.

---

Looking at your code, I'm not sure you need the `-1` in conditions such as `if (bombs[i][1] < heigth-step-1):`.  Clearly these checks are trying to stop you going off the edge of the grid, but the extra `-1` is unnecessary.  I'm also a bit concerned about `step`: is this equal to `1`?  You are including `step` in your checks for falling off the right-hand side or the bottom of the grid, but not when falling off the top or left-hand side, so if `step` is greater than 1 you may run into problems.  (For example, if `step` is 3 and `bombs[i][0]` is 1, `bombs[i][0] - step` will be `-2`.)

Also, can I make a couple of suggestions about your code from a readability point of view?  Firstly, you are repeating `bombs[i][0]` and `bombs[i][1]` a lot: if you add lines `x = bombs[i][0]` and `y = bombs[i][1]` you could write `x` and `y` instead of `bombs[i][0]` and `bombs[i][1]` in the rest of the loop.  Secondly, instead of writing `some_expression = some_expression + 1` you can write `some_expression += 1`.  Making these changes would shorten a line such as

```py
numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] = numbers[(bombs[i][0]-step, bombs[i][1]-step)] + 1
```

to

```
numbers[(x-step, y-step)] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, removing a level of indentation helped :-)
"step" is the size of the fields, it is a number which can only be greater than 20... It doesn´t change while running! 
I will make the changes to improve my code.
Thanks
JanF_04